# Texting to an email address error

Tags: android, email, text, sms

I am trying to set up a simple texting application to text some information to an email server. I am currently using the following method:

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {        
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, SMSTestActivity.class), 0);                
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
    }
```

If I set the phoneNumber string to an email address, it will not send the message, reiterating "Message failed. Would you like to try again?" five times before it won't ask anymore and just doesn't send the text. The app works with a phone number string input. I thought the issue was resolved when I switched from the gsm.SmsManager deprecated class to the new one, but this didn't fix the issue. I'm not terribly well versed in Android, so there may be a simple error somewhere, I just don't know how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an email use:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            emailIntent .setType("plain/text");

            emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"example@gmail.com"});

            emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject of the Email");

            //emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myBodyText);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));

        }

    });
```

Comment: I was hoping to send a text as this would not use up data. Our app is collecting data and it would be sending a lot of texts/emails. I did find a solution to the problem in using SMS gateways. You can send a message to 6245 with the body content "recipient" + "(subject)" + "body" and it will work on Verizon. T-Mobile uses 500, AT&T uses 121, and Sprint uses 6245.